# What does 思うところがあった mean in そして元々身体が弱かった母が二年前に病気で亡くなった時、リーゼも思うところがあったのだろう。以来リーゼは叔母夫婦の元で家事手伝いをしている。

Tags: words

Context:

> ただ、才能があるといってもカイルほどではなかったが、その分リーゼは努力し、随分と腕を上げた。将来はこれを活かした道に進みたいと、常々言っていたほどだ。
>   だがリーゼが生まれる前に夫を戦争で亡くし、一人でリーゼを育ててきた彼女の母は、決して口には出さなかったものの、娘には平穏な道を歩んでほしかったはずだ。
>   　そして元々身体が弱かった母が二年前に病気で亡くなった時、「リーゼも思うところがあった」のだろう。以来リーゼは叔母夫婦の元で家事手伝いをしている。

From what I've found on stack it may mean part, so I assumed in this case it might be a reason, something like "Rize also had her reasons", but its based on nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, リーゼ had wanted to choose some unusual (non-平穏) way of making a living, but she gave it up after her mother died two years ago. She gave up because she had "思うところ" about the death.

思うところがある (literally "there is a point of consideration") is a set phrase which vaguely means something like "one has some strong inner thoughts (about something)." Depending on the context, 思うところがありました can mean "I was (somehow) deeply impressed", "I had a certain reason (which I don't want to disclose)", "It made me (re)think", "I had a (secret) idea" etc.

In this context, リーゼ thought "something" about her mother's death, the detail of which is untold. The sentence says her mother's death made her think deeply, and it led her to change her mind.

Answer (score 2):

> (0)「リーゼも**思うところがあった**」

「思うところ」とは「内心で考えていること」という意味ですが、「単に考えている」ではなく、他人には伝えていませんが、「これをすると決心していること」に近い意味です。

(1) Questioner: Rize also had her reasons. リーゼにも彼女なりの理由があった
(2) Me: There was **something** that Lise had also intended to do.　リーゼにもこうしようと心に決めていることがあった。

文脈全体から判断すると(1)は意訳ですが、大変上手に(0)の意味を表現していると思います。

文脈全体からみるとリーゼには次の２つの選択肢がありました。
(3) リーゼが最初から持っており更に努力で向上させた彼女の**才能**を活かした職業
(4) リーゼを女手一人で育ててきた病弱で死んだ母親が望んだ**平穏な道**

文全体は次のような意味です。
リーゼが「思うところのもの」すなわち、「心に決めたあること」は、「母親が望んだ平穏な道」だったので、叔母夫婦の元で家事手伝いをしている。

リーゼがいつ平穏な道を選択したのか、あるいは、死んだ母親が本当にリーゼに平穏な道を歩んで欲しかったかどうかは明示されておりません。書かれているのは、「母は、決して**口には出さなかった**ものの、娘には平穏な道を歩んでほしかった**はず**だ」と「母が二年前に病気で亡くなった時、「リーゼも思うところがあった」の**だろう**。」です。
しかし、作者は読者に暗示的に示した文を断定的に読んで欲しいので書き表しているのでしょうから、あたかも明示されているように理解するべきなのでしょう。

私が答えを用意しているときにnarutoさんの回答がありました。narutoさんと私の回答ではほぼ似ておりますが、次の点が少し違います。
naruto: She gave up because she had "思うところ" about the death.
私: リーゼの思うところは、自分は「お世話になった母親が自分にして欲しい思っていたであろうことを選ぼう」ということです。